# SparkStreaming, RabbitMQ and MQTT in python using pika

Tags: python, apache-spark, rabbitmq, mqtt, pika

Just to make things tricky, I'd like to consume messages from the rabbitMQ queue. Now I know there is a plugin for MQTT on rabbit (https://www.rabbitmq.com/mqtt.html).

However I cannot seem to make an example work where Spark consumes a message that has been produced from pika.

For example I am using the simple wordcount.py program here (https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.2.0/streaming-programming-guide.html) to see if I can I see a message **producer** in the following way:

```
import sys
import pika
import json
import future
import pprofile

def sendJson(json):

  connection = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters(host='localhost'))
  channel = connection.channel()

  channel.queue_declare(queue='analytics', durable=True)
  channel.queue_bind(exchange='analytics_exchange',
                       queue='analytics')

  channel.basic_publish(exchange='analytics_exchange', routing_key='analytics',body=json)
  connection.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
  with open(sys.argv[1],'r') as json_file:
    sendJson(json_file.read())
```

The sparkstreaming **consumer** is the following:

```
import sys
import operator

from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.streaming import StreamingContext
from pyspark.streaming.mqtt import MQTTUtils

sc = SparkContext(appName="SS")
sc.setLogLevel("ERROR")
ssc = StreamingContext(sc, 1)
ssc.checkpoint("checkpoint")
#ssc.setLogLevel("ERROR")


#RabbitMQ

"""EXCHANGE = 'analytics_exchange'
EXCHANGE_TYPE = 'direct'
QUEUE = 'analytics'
ROUTING_KEY = 'analytics'
RESPONSE_ROUTING_KEY = 'analytics-response'
"""


brokerUrl = "localhost:5672" # "tcp://iot.eclipse.org:1883"
topic = "analytics"

mqttStream = MQTTUtils.createStream(ssc, brokerUrl, topic)
#dummy functions - nothing interesting...
words = mqttStream.flatMap(lambda line: line.split(" "))
pairs = words.map(lambda word: (word, 1))
wordCounts = pairs.reduceByKey(lambda x, y: x + y)

wordCounts.pprint()
ssc.start()
ssc.awaitTermination()
```

However unlike the simple wordcount example, I cannot get this to work and get the following error:

```
16/06/16 17:41:35 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 7.0 (TID 8)
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttConnectOptions.validateURI(MqttConnectOptions.java:457)
    at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttAsyncClient.<init>(MqttAsyncClient.java:273)
```

So my questions are, what should be the settings in terms of `MQTTUtils.createStream(ssc, brokerUrl, topic)` to listen into the queue and whether there are any more fuller examples and how these map onto those of rabbitMQ.

I am running my consumer code with: `./bin/spark-submit ../../bb/code/skunkworks/sparkMQTTRabbit.py`

I have updated the producer code as follows with TCP parameters as suggested by one comment:

```
url_location = 'tcp://localhost'
url = os.environ.get('', url_location)
params = pika.URLParameters(url)
connection = pika.BlockingConnection(params)
```

and the spark streaming as:

```
brokerUrl = "tcp://127.0.0.1:5672"
topic = "#" #all messages

mqttStream = MQTTUtils.createStream(ssc, brokerUrl, topic)
records = mqttStream.flatMap(lambda line: json.loads(line))
count = records.map(lambda rec: len(rec))
total = count.reduce(lambda a, b: a + b)
total.pprint()
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like you are using wrong port number. Assuming that:

- you have a local instance of RabbitMQ running with default settings and you've enabled MQTT plugin (`rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_mqtt`) and restarted RabbitMQ server
- included `spark-streaming-mqtt` when executing `spark-submit` / `pyspark` (either with `packages` or `jars` / `driver-class-path`)

you can connect using TCP with `tcp://localhost:1883`. You have to also remember that MQTT is using `amq.topic`.

**Quick start**:

- create `Dockerfile` with following content:

  ```
  FROM rabbitmq:3-management

  RUN rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_mqtt
  ```
- build Docker image:

  ```
  docker build -t rabbit_mqtt .
  ```
- start image and wait until server is ready:

  ```
  docker run -p 15672:15672 -p 5672:5672 -p 1883:1883 rabbit_mqtt
  ```
- create `producer.py` with following content:

  ```
  import pika
  import time 


  connection = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters(
      host='localhost'))
  channel = connection.channel()
  channel.exchange_declare(exchange='amq.topic',
                   type='topic', durable=True)

  for i in range(1000):
      channel.basic_publish(
          exchange='amq.topic',  # amq.topic as exchange
          routing_key='hello',   # Routing key used by producer
          body='Hello World {0}'.format(i)
      )
      time.sleep(3)

  connection.close()
  ```
- start producer

  ```
  python producer.py
  ```

  and visit management console http://127.0.0.1:15672/#/exchanges/%2F/amq.topic

  to see that messages are received.
- create `consumer.py` with following content:

  ```
  from pyspark import SparkContext
  from pyspark.streaming import StreamingContext
  from pyspark.streaming.mqtt import MQTTUtils

  sc = SparkContext()
  ssc = StreamingContext(sc, 10)

  mqttStream = MQTTUtils.createStream(
      ssc, 
      "tcp://localhost:1883",  # Note both port number and protocol
      "hello"                  # The same routing key as used by producer
  )
  mqttStream.count().pprint()
  ssc.start()
  ssc.awaitTermination()
  ssc.stop()
  ```
- download dependencies (adjust Scala version to the one used to build Spark and Spark version):

  ```
  mvn dependency:get -Dartifact=org.apache.spark:spark-streaming-mqtt_2.11:1.6.1
  ```
- make sure `SPARK_HOME` and `PYTHONPATH` point to the correct directories.
- submit `consumer.py` with (adjust versions as before):

  ```
  spark-submit --packages org.apache.spark:spark-streaming-mqtt_2.11:1.6.1 consumer.py
  ```

If you followed all the steps you should see Hello world messages in the Spark log.

Comment: Thanks. I'll take a look. Can this work with direct and well as topic?

Comment: MQTT plugin [can be configured](https://www.rabbitmq.com/mqtt.html#config) to use different exchange but as far as I can tell this it. MQTT protocol is not much richer than that anyway.

Comment: Is there a way to configure this without docker - for example using the .config file. I have tried with the default settings in https://www.rabbitmq.com/mqtt.html. But this does not work at all. With no settings, my spark listener can connect with the following: =INFO REPORT==== 5-Jul-2016::11:52:08 ===
accepting MQTT connection <0.321.0> (127.0.0.1:47868 -> 127.0.0.1:1883). But how to make the produced messages map onto this port?

Comment: Docker is not crucial here but I don't really understand the question. Port is not a property of message. I It is a global property of the server. If topics and exchange match there should be no reason for any issues. What do you mean by "it doesn't work"? When you check RabbitMQ UI do you see bindings from producer? How about consumer? Does routing keys match?

Comment: I had tried using the standard message queue we use. I now tried using the topic without queue and this seems to work right out of the box. However didn't use Docker.

Comment: This answer is great. Now were are trying a more refined solution. @zero323 however the typical use case we have is a direct exchange with a queue bound to this exchange. I have not seen anyway to make this work sadly. Any suggestions how we might use the direct approach?

Answer (score 2):

From the `MqttAsyncClient` Javadoc, the server URI must have one of the following schemes: `tcp://`, `ssl://`, or `local://`.  You need to change your `brokerUrl` above to have one of these schemes.

For more information, here's a link to the source for `MqttAsyncClient`:

https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.java/blob/master/org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3/src/main/java/org/eclipse/paho/client/mqttv3/MqttAsyncClient.java#L272

Comment: I attempted to change the producer to use tcp instead of http, however I found that I now get a connection issue of the following:  ERROR ReceiverSupervisorImpl: Stopped receiver with error: Connection lost (32109) - java.net.SocketException: Connection reset