# Consuming from a RabbitMQ queue with Spark streaming and python

Tags: apache-spark, rabbitmq, pyspark, mqtt

After managing to get Spark Streaming to listen to rabbitMQ in python, which is working via a topic exchange (see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37863801/sparkstreaming-rabbitmq-and-mqtt-in-python-using-pika)). I would now like to consume messages from a queue. Is there a way to do this?

Using the `MQTT` adaptor

```
from pyspark.streaming.mqtt import MQTTUtils

sc = SparkContext("local[2]", "Process")
ssc = StreamingContext(sc, 5)
routing_key = 'analytics'
mqttStream = MQTTUtils.createStream(ssc, "tcp://localhost:1883", routing_key)
```

Here is what I have in the `POM.xml`:

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
<artifactId>spark-streaming-mqtt_2.11</artifactId>
<version>1.6.1</version>
</dependency>
```

In summary, I publish to the exchange, I see the messages load into the bound queue, but I seem to be able to find no way in Spark with which to consume from this queue.

Comment: Is MQTT a must have here? There is some experimental AMQP plugin and Stratio has full RabbitMQ connector.

Comment: @zero323 only requirement is that its python. When I looked at Stratio, there were no python bindings :(...unless you know differently?

Comment: Writing Python bindings is tedious but not impossible, but you're right.